# Using Objective-C and SQLite, loop thought records in DB and set a value that increments for each row

Tags: sqlite

I have an app that stores data entered by the user. Now I have a dilemma as one client added 15,000 records before syncing the data, so now it times out when trying to sync.

After checking the code, I noticed that the awesome developer that built the app added an ID field that it supposed to auto increment, but he didn't set it to auto increment so it is now NULL for each row.

Could anyone possibly help with a Sqlite script that will update the ID for each row with an increment ion value? Some sort of FOR loop?

The database is emptied after each sync, so the loop can start at 1 each time.

Comment: I don't think anybody can help to write code for you. Stackoverflow is not a code writing services. What you need to do is attempt to do what you want by yourself, and when you face problem, then you can ask here.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thats isn't really my intention, its more of the SQLite script that has me thrown. Ill edit the question.